# Como copiar um canvas para uma imagem

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Tenho me debatido pra resolver essa questão, que parece simples, mas não estou conseguindo,

Talvez eu não esteja **sabendo fazer a pergunta**, então conto com a **boa vontade** dos amigos:

**1. Tenho o seguinte canvas:**

->

```
var placeholder = document.querySelector('.flot-base');
var context = placeholder.getContext('2d');
```

Assim como outro canvas de teste

```
var c   = document.getElementById('analysisFullGraph1');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
```

Com essa funcao consigo copiar facimente uma parte do canvas "placehoder" para o canvas "ctx"

```
function copy{
    var imgData = context.getImageData(684, 0, 784, 250);
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 100, 0);
}
```

=>

1. **porem estou tentando copiar do canvas  para uma outra imagem, mas
   nao tive sucesso...**

por exemplo:

```
<html>
    <img id='analysisFullGraph1'  src="full_graphics.png" />
</html>

<script>
var placeholder = document.querySelector('.flot-base');
var context = placeholder.getContext('2d');

var imageCTX  = document.getElementById('analysisFullGraph1');

function copy{
    var imgData = context.getImageData(684, 0, 784, 250);
    imageCTX.putImageData(imgData, 100, 0);
}
</script>
```

Como fazer essa copia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não confunda um objeto de imagem com um contexto 2d do canvas. O único que pode ser alterado em uma imagem do HTML é a sua fonte (`Image().src`).

Continuando, será mais simples para fazer o que você quer:

Você não precisa de `ImageData()` para fazer isso, você pode renderizar um pedaço do outro canvas usando diretamente `ctx.drawImage(Image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)`, onde o ponto s indica o ponto de renderização do quadro da imagem, e cada parâmetro começando com `"d"` indica os destinos de onde desenhar a imagem. Quando pelo menos somente 5 parâmetros abaixo são especificados, eles se tornam nessa sequência: `Image, dx, dy, dw, dh`.

```
var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d')

canvas2.width = imageCTX.width
canvas2.height = imageCTX.height

context2.drawImage(imageCTX, 0, 0)

context2.drawImage(c,
            /* parâmetros de corte */
            684, 0, 784, 250,
            /* destinos de desenho (x, y, largura, altura) */
            10, 0, c.width, c.height)

imageCTX.src = canvas2.toDataURL()
```

Só para lembrar, `ctx.putImageData` renderiza um `ImageData` em uma forma que atravessa o `ImageData` atual do canvas, sem perceber a transparência dos pixels.

Se você realmente quer usar `ctx.putImageData` você pode criar 2 canvas anônimos, assim o `canvas2` será desenhado com a `ImageData` do canvas `c`, e o `canvas3` será desenhado com a imagem desejada, em seguida desenhado com `canvas2` usando `ctx.drawImage` (pois canvas é tratado como uma imagem), e finalmente > `imageCTX.src = canvas3.toDataURL()`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44978/discussion-on-answer-by-nicematt-como-copiar-um-canvas-para-uma-imagem)

Answer (score 3):

Uma possibilidade para efetuar a cópia dos dados do *canvas* para a imagem (DOM), é utilizar o método [toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), do elemento canvas (não do contexto!).

Este método, retorna a representação da imagem em um formato *URI* (padrão PNG, mas pode ser alterado por parâmetro), por exemplo: `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA..."`.

O código para cópia fica:

```
var dados = placeholder.toDataURL();
imageCTX.setAttribute('src', dados);
```

---

Veja funcionando no *jsfiddle*: [Cópia - Canvas Para Img](https://jsfiddle.net/gomiero/r05g9dLw/)

Comment: Mas o op quer copiar um pedaço só

Comment: O título da pergunta é "Como copiar um canvas para imagem", não uma parte dele. Existem outras formas de fazer essa cópia, mas se a resposta do @nicematt (mais completa) lhe ajudou, aceite-a como resposta correta :)

Comment: talvez fosse interessante saber que, nos que fazermos a pergunta.... nao sabemos exatamente o que queremos...  por isso estamos tentando aprender e no processo perguntando errado... nao sei mais como expressar essa questao..  ja tentei de varias formas...  por favor desculpem o mau jeito... mas eh frustrante...

Comment: @RobervalSena山本 mas é perguntando que nós aprendemos! Não se sinta frustrado por isso! Acredito que todos aqui já passaram por isso e ainda passam, pois novas tecnologias surgem todos os dias. IMO,  perguntar é bem mais difícil que responder :)